# c# - bit parsing 8 byte array

Tags: c#, parsing, bit

Bytes: 240 255 255 9 0 224 9 0

f0 ff ff 09 00 E0 09 00

Little endian unsigned int 64 translation:

00 09 E0 00 09 ff ff f0

```
int value1 = 0-19 bits  
int value2 = 20-39 bits 
int value3 = 40-59 bits
int value4 = 60-62 bits 
bool value5 = 63 bit

value1 = (uint)(byteArray[0] | byteArray[1] << 8 | (byteArray[2] << 16)) & 0x14;
```

Am I doing this correctly? I keep getting value of 0 but should be 158.

Comment: What is the intent of the `& 0x14`? That might be your problem.

Comment: Also: why are you trying to store 64 bits in 5 `int`s? Why not `byte[]` or `long`/`ulong`?

Comment: Are you trying to store RGBA - value with 20bits per channel (20-20-20-4) or something similar? 0x14 should be about 5 "F" - `0xFFFFF`... or your braces are wrong as The Moof suggested.

Comment: I'm parsing a file which has byte array of size 8. I have to parse 5 variables from the 8 bytes.

Comment: ((byteArray[0] | byteArray[1] << 8 | (byteArray[2] << 16))) & 0xfffff     this still gives me wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

The last operation in your calculation is `& 0x14`.  This will do a bitwise and against the binary value of `0001 0100`. You're looking for the first 20 bits, so your mask should be `0xfffff`.

Comment: yeah I was trying to mask off the 20 bits because it was currently 24 bits long. So i assume 0x14 being 20 in decimal, it would mask it.       (uint)(byteArray[0] | byteArray[1] << 8 | (byteArray[2] << 16)) & 0xfffff; still gives me 2304.

Comment: Based on your rules, the first number would be `0x00900`, which is 2304.

Comment: Keep in mind that bit values are read right-to-left.  Based on your expected answer, it leads me to believe that the rules are incorrect.  They should be Val1 = bits 44-63, Val2 = bits 24-43, etc.  Using these rules with the Little Endian bytes, you will get the expected values.

Comment: The specification sheet for this particular file(which I can't specify what it is), says that's how the bits are stored and what order.

Comment: The bit order isn't the problem.  As I said, numbering your bits backwards.